# Reshaping NumPy Array: IndexError: Tuple Index Out of Range

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples

I'm currently trying to learn about the LSTM Algorithm (Machine Learning) and trying to "reshape" my (NumPy) X test data array. However I seem to have a problem regarding the size of the array, I think!?

Note: I've looked at the question [reshaping of an nparray returned "IndexError: tuple index out of range"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54391166/reshaping-of-an-nparray-returned-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range)
which I do understand, but I can't apply this to my particular situation.

```
 inputs = new_data[len(new_data) - len(valid) - 60:].values
 inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
 inputs  = scaler.transform(inputs)

 X_test = []
 for i in range(60,inputs.shape[0]):
      X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i,0])
      X_test = np.array(X_test)

 #problem starts here:

 X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))
 scores = model.predict(X_test)
 scores = scaler.inverse_transform(scores)
```

The error I get:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call   last)
<ipython-input-28-ac22155ae52a> in <module>
 ----> 1 X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))
  2 scores = model.predict(X_test)
  3 scores = scaler.inverse_transform(scores)

 IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any pointers would be great. Note: The data set consists of an Excel file with a Date column and a scores column.

Comment: `X_test` is probably one dimensional.  You overwrite it each step of your loop.  You probably want to move `X_test = np.array(X_test)` *after* you're loop

Comment: Are you able to elaborate a bit on this? I've placed X_test after the for loop but I'm still having issues