# Getting an error during reshaping the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, reshape

My code is:

```
last_steps = valid[['Close']].tail(60)
last_values = np.reshape(last_steps, ( -1, last_steps.shape[1], last_steps.shape[2]))
```

The second line rises this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\UTKARS~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8696/2291656061.py in <module>
      1 last_steps = valid[['Close']].tail(60)
----> 2 last_values = np.reshape(last_steps, ( -1, last_steps.shape[1], last_steps.shape[2]))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reshaping of an nparray returned "IndexError: tuple index out of range"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54391166/reshaping-of-an-nparray-returned-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are providing indices wrong.  Indices start from 0 in Python.

Comment: Can you send code.

Answer (score 0):

you should check whether the `last_steps` variable has a 3-dimensional shape to call `last_steps.shape[2]`. you can just print it with `print(last_steps.shape)`. `shape` function returns a tuple of the shape of an array.

it will print `(5,2)` if it's 2-dimensional. when you call `last_steps.shape[0]` it will returns `5`

it will print `(8,3,9)` if it's 3-dimensional. when you call `last_steps.shape[2]` it will returns `9`

and so on

**Edit**

After carefully looking into your code, I assume `valid` is a DataFrame. DataFrame is a 2-dimensional array. so I'm pretty sure when you execute `last_steps.shape`, it should return `(60,1)`.